# Rank of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

How to find the Rank of Operator A, acting in $\mathbb R^{2\times 2} \ $ by the rule:
$$AX=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}X$$

I'm told: The rank of a linear operator is equal to the rank of its matrix in its arbitrary pair of basis.

Comment: Did you try to apply the definition that you mention? Do you know what the rank of a matrix is?

Comment: I know what the rank of a matrix is. If you have eg e1(1,0,0), e2(0,1,0),e3(0,0,1) they are linearly independent.

Comment: To try and head off confusion, while the matrix $A$ has rank one, it is not true that the operator "multiplication on the left by $A$" acting on $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ is a linear operator of rank one.  The rank of an operator is dimension of its image.

Comment: @user280447 Than what exactly aren't you able to solve of your question? (BTW, yours is not a *definition* of rank; it is just an example of a matrix with rank 3)

Comment: @giomasce The comment above mine had asked if I knew what linearly independent means. I answered both questions and wasn't giving a definition of rank.

Comment: @Leo103 Then I do not get which problem you have in applying the definition and finding the answer by yourself. I can help you if you want to, but I need to know where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank of the operator $T: \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$, defined by $T(X) = AX$, agrees with the rank of its matrix representation with respect to any pair of (ordered) bases for the domain and codomain.

For simplicity let's use the same basis for both:

$$ \mathscr{B} = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} ,
 \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} ,
 \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} ,
 \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\} $$

With respect to this (ordered) basis, the representation of the linear operator:

$$ A \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix} a+c & b+d \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

is $M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$.  The rank of $M$ is two, as is the rank of linear operator $T$.

Comment: so the first row of M ie (1000) is from $\begin{pmatrix}
1+0 & 0+0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\$ right? -Thanks

Comment: Right, if you multiply the first basis element by $A$, you get the same basis element back, so in our matrix representation of the linear operator $T$, this gives a $1$ on the diagonal for that element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not cleared the concept of Rank of a linear transformation, So just to clarify that Here is the theory.

An $n\times m$ matrix $A$ can be used to define a linear transformation $L_A\colon\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ given by $L_A(\mathbf{v}) = A\mathbf{v}$. If we do this, the kernel of $L_A$ equals the nullspace of $A$, and the image of $L_A$ equals the column-space of $A$. In particular, $\mathrm{rank}(A) = \mathrm{rank}(L_A)$, $\mathrm{nullity}(A)=\mathrm{nullity}(L_A)$.

Going the other way, given a linear transformation $T\colon V\to W$, if we pick a basis $\alpha$ for $V$ and a basis $\beta$ for $W$, then we can define a matrix called the *coordinate matrix of $T$ with respect to $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $[T]_{\alpha}^{\beta}$, which is a $\dim(W)\times\dim(V)$ matrix whose columns are the coordinate vectors, relative to $\beta$, of the images under $T$ of the vectors in $\alpha$. The matrix has the property that for every $\mathbf{v}\in V$,
$$[T]_{\alpha}^{\beta}[\mathbf{v}]_{\alpha} = [T(\mathbf{v})]_{\beta}$$
where $[\mathbf{v}]_{\alpha}$ is the coordinate vector of $\mathbf{v}$ with respect to the basis $\alpha$, and $[T(\mathbf{v})]_{\beta}$ is the coordinate vector of $T(\mathbf{v})$ with respect to $\beta$. If we do this, then the rank of $T$ equals the rank of $[T]_{\alpha}^{\beta}$, and the nullity of $T$ equals the nullity of $[T]_{\alpha}^{\beta}$.

So the notions of rank and nullity for matrices and for linear transformations correspond to one another under the correspondence between matrices and linear transformations.

I hope this must clear all your doubts.